# Apply Coupon Button disappeared on Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been reformatting the Coupon Code box on the Woocommerce checkout page. It was originally huge and at the top of the page, which is terrible design because people will see the big coupon code box and leave your site to go look for a coupon, then never come back.

I have the coupon box where I want and it works just fine if you press enter. The issue is that you can't see the Apply button. It is right below the coupon code box. If you hover over it, the little hand cursor appears. You just can't see it.

How can I get the button to appear to the right of the coupon code box on desktop? It'll get pushed below it on mobile.

You will have to add an item to the cart to see the checkout page: http://198.199.114.131/shop/

Checkout page: http://198.199.114.131/checkout/

Comment: I see the background is set to none. Before that, was there an icon?

Comment: Yeah. I copied this code from the Cart page of the theme (this is the Checkout page). On the Cart page, an arrow icon shows up when you click into the box so I took out the Apply Coupon wording because they overlapped. I'm going to spend some time figuring out how to get it to show up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this style to your theme style.css or any frontend custom css file:

```
form.checkout_coupon input[type="submit"] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #dba633 !important;
    width: 48% !important;
}
form.checkout_coupon{
    width:100% !important;
}
form.checkout_coupon #coupon_code{
    width:50% !important;
}
```

Comment: Is !important so important?

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
input[name="apply_coupon"] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    float: left;
    background-color: bisque !important;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em !important;
}
```

Comment: That will apply to all buttons. The specific target here is ../shopkeeper/css/styles.css?ver=2.4.9 and line number 15831. Better to use custom CSS box given in the theme options without over-killing important.

Comment: @ManojKumar yeah i fixed

Comment: But min-width: 100% will stretch it to the whole coupon box. :(

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it's the `background: none !important;` that's not letting you see anything near the coupon box. Remove that piece of code and you can see the button, however, there is no text on the button.

To put the button under the coupon code input box, remove the `background: none !important;` where you have specified it and then add the following code in your theme's custom CSS or child theme's CSS file:

```
.woocommerce-cart .entry-content .woocommerce .actions .coupon .button {
    top: 60px;
}
```

Currently, `top: 3px;` is specified.

To display the text, add this code to your theme's custom CSS or child theme's CSS file:

```
.woocommerce-cart .entry-content .woocommerce .actions .coupon .button:before {
    content: "Apply Coupon";
}
```

You can change the `Apply Coupon` text to whatever text you want to display there.

What I have offered above is a workaround as I do not know what edits you made to the coupon box during your reformatting, but it should solve your problem.

Hope this helps.